# PayPal Pro doesn't valid data - almost always Success

Tags: validation, paypal, sandbox, gateway

I'm trying to implement Paypal Pro Gateway to my e-commerce. I created appropriate account for developers and sandbox.

My problem is that I almost always get the "Success" or "SuccessWithWarning" respond. It's wrong in my opinion because e.g. I use wrong "expires on" (for card) or information for buyer (I created one).

My seller gets new payments but the balance for my buyer is still the same.

Should not sandbox validate data like that? I don't know in other way how to test my form.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox is left pretty open for testing purposes.  Unless you use an expiration year prior to the current year it'll pretty much accept anything as far as that goes.

If you want to test specific error conditions you can do that with "[Negative Testing](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/)".